# Vibrancy not working with UIVisualEffectView from Storyboard

Tags: ios, storyboard, uivisualeffectview

I have create a nib file to design a custom TableViewCell with Storyboard.
Therefor I used an VisualEffectView with Blur and Vibrancy (Nested UIVisualEffectView objects with blur and vibrancy effects.).

In view hierarchy I put this below the content view of the TableViewCell.

I add some textfields and image views below the view of the uivisualeffectview.

My problem is, if i don't set the vibrancy property at the visualeffectview, all 3 light versions are working fine. 
If i activate the vibrancy property, i see the text color effect, but the blur is not working anymore.

Comment: hi @kext: i wrote a short post about using UIVisualEffect in Interface builder, http://dannyshmueli.com/blog/2015/03/07/interface-builder-and-blur-with-vibrancy/

Comment: Hi ugiflezet, I have already fixed the problem. But for me it is confusing how it is implemented in Interface builder. If you add a Visual Effect View with Vibrancy, you will get this nested Effect View. Both have the option for blur style and vibrancy. In my tests the option blur style in the main Effect View is obsolete and the vibrancy must not be set. If you add the simple Visual Effect View with Blur, you will also have the option for Vibrancy. This is also not a good for a clear workflow.

Comment: i agree, there are caveats to this kind of hierarchy, but i guess this is the way we have to do it right now.

Comment: I implemented a sample code of using UIVisualEffect using storyboard. Feel free to look at my demo at https://github.com/Vaberer/BlurTransition.